# In search of a Jyothishya text: Chaturmukha nADi

Tags: astrology

I came across a Jyotisha Shastra text by name Chaturmukha nADi.  A Madhwa scholar had cited from this text for some verses on Shankaracharya and Madhwacharya.  On a search on the internet I could not get any information whatsoever about this text.  I request members to help locating the text.

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but your best bet is likely in the shops at Udupi where Madhwacharya's ashta matha functions.

Comment: @FrankenCode I'll keep that in mind, though I doubt I'll ever end up going there. Thanks.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar The terms themselves are mentioned in Yoga Yajnavalkaya idk Sanskrit though. https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_yoga/yogayAjnyavalkya.itx

Comment: Thanks.  I am not in doubt about the terms 'chaturmukha and nADi'.  I am looking for a Jyotisha text by the name 'chaturmukha nADi.'  Udupi is a likely place.  I shall too look for it there.

Comment: @Haridasa Thanks, will have a look, maybe it can offer some hints.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar perhaps.

Comment: @Haridasa Nevermind, as S. Vaidyanathan said, the text doesn't contain that info all together "chaturmukha nADi". And, separate mention isn't very useful, unfortunately.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar maybe look into some of Madhavas followers works.

Comment: I also have another question you could answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'll get to looking further for Chaturmukha Naadi after I finish reading Chandrakalaa Naadi and Jaata PariJaata. Probably next year. As for anything else, you can contact me on Discord. @Haridasa

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar okay bud I already contacted you somewhat I am curious if Manu is interplorated, or is it an indologist's lie?